# Java Spring Data JPA Composite ID with foreign key

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am making a Spring web service to learn more about it and I am currently mapping the database. I have a table that has a composite ID, where one of the ID's is a foreign key to another table (ManytoOne).

| Creditors | Creditor_Invoices |
| --- | --- |
| ID | Creditor_ID |
| name | Invoice_ID |

As anywhere you buy something they use their own way of making ID's it has a composite ID like this.
My Current code:
Serializable class CInvoiceId:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class CInvoiceId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creditors_id", nullable = false)
    private Creditor cInvoiceCreditorId;
    @Column(name = "invoice_id", nullable = false)
    private String cInvoiceId;

    public CInvoiceId(Creditor creditor, String cInvoiceId){
        this.cInvoiceCreditorId = creditor;
        this.cInvoiceId = cInvoiceId;
    }

    //Setters, Getters, Equals and Hash
}
```

My Creditor class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "creditors")
public class Creditor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int creditorId;

    @Column(name = "name",nullable = false)
    private String creditorName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cInvoiceCreditorId")
    private List<CInvoice> cInvoices;
}
```

My CInvoice class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "c_invoices")
public class CInvoice {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CInvoiceId cInvoiceID;
}
```

When I start it to try and test it I get the error that it can not find the mapped by from the creditor class, but I don't know what I should map it to as the ID is now made in the CInvoiceId class. What should it be?

Regards
Dany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "derived identities" to map these classes:

Creditor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "creditors")
public class Creditor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name",nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creditor")
    private List<CInvoice> invoices;
}
```

CInvoiceId:

```
@Embeddable
public class CInvoiceId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "invoice_id", nullable = false)
    private String invoiceID;

    private int creditorID; // corresponds to PK type of Creditor

    // ...
}
```

CInvoice:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "c_invoices")
public class CInvoice {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CInvoiceId id;

    @MapsId("creditorID") // maps creditorID attribute of embedded id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creditors_id", nullable = false)
    Creditor creditor;
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.